# How to write this in Latex?

Tags: math-mode

[image]

Please see the image? How to write this in latex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Postings of the "do this for me-request" variety are generally discouraged on this site. Please tell us what you've tried so far. That does the "this" in "how to write this in LaTeX" refer to? The font style? All three lines shown in the screenshot, or just a subset of lines? Please be specific.

Comment: See the `cases` environment of the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Are $(a)$ and $(b)$ obtained by hand,or are they in an enumerate environment?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item
        \begin{align}
            y \equiv 0 &
        \end{align}
    \item
        \begin{align}
            \begin{cases}
                y = \left(\frac{2}{3}x\right)^{3/2} & x \ge 0 \\
                y = 0 & x \le 0
            \end{cases}
        \end{align}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking care of this! Would you mind moving `x` to the numerator and replacing `=` by `\equiv` to make the thing a bit closer to the OP's picture?